# Shortcut for matching opening and closing tags in MXML (Flash Builder)

Tags: mxml, flash-builder, shortcut

Do you know if it's possible to match the opening and closing tag in MXML with Flash Builder 4.x? 
In AS3 you can see the curly braces highlighted and you can type Ctrl+Shift+P to jump from one bracket to the other. 
In DreamWeaver you can see the hierarchy for every HTML element, and you can click any HTML element to highlight the block inside. 

There isn't anything in Flash Builder to help us with these tasks? 
I can see only icons with - and + for contract or expand the MXML blocks, but they are working wrong !